# Automation tool for testing integration of a Web application with a desktop application?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am new to Test automation and would like to try my hand at automating a web application project.

This web application gets its data from a desktop application (on syncing). I was thinking that selenium is the best approach to automate web side but there would be test cases where I need to use the desktop app here. (e.g. checking the sync changes coming from desktop app into web, validating the data, etc.)
How best to combine both the desktop and web app automation? can we use selenium here?

Desktop application runs only on Window OS. (.exe application) Technology used: C#.

Web application is compatible with any browser (preferred - chrome, firefox). Technology used: Java.

Comment: "What is the Best tool"  are quickly closed (as you will find out) because they are not answerable. We have so many tools because every one is "best" in their own niche. So you have to describe your problem in more details to get answer. Your lack of experience does not allow you to give us enough details. **This is normal** you just need to learn more. Don't try to look for shortcuts (there are none): invest time to learn the tools.

Comment: you can try the test complete tool and its compatible for both desktop and web application.

Comment: For anything with desktop automation, Sikuli is worth a look, and, on Windows, SeeShell and the SeeShell Browser (Chromium with builtin machine vision)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure Java test coding you can go with the below combination:

- Selenium for Web part
- Winnium for Desktop part

You will be able to seamlessly call the API within the same java starting class.If you want the two applications to interact in a test workflow, this combo might be worth a try. Also the Winnium API is quite similar to Selenium so the learning curve is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Being purely GUI driven with machine vision, Sikuli is always worth a look for situations where app(s) under test don't have readily available hooks, the automation has to migrate between platforms, access VNC's, etc.

However from description of what you need (app A gets data for app B) it is worth noting Sikuli is pretty useless for validating anything past what it sees - basically UX and that's it. If the data passed can be validated in functional UX/UAT type tests, then it can probably work for what you're looking for.

A good compromise might be to use Sikuli API in Selenium framework.

Comment: Thanks @hal !!
I need to lookup on what Sikuli does but happy to know that this can be done.